# How do I do a mock test for validations? using the controller which is an api implementation

Tags: java

Guys I have the following code

My interfaz

```
public class MyRequest {
  @NotNull 
  private String dato;
  ......
}


public interface HelloApi {
@Operation(summary = "Hello Word")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "HelloWord" = {
                    @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema =  @Schema(implementation = MyClass.class))}),

    })
    @PostMapping(value = ENDPOINT_DESCUENTOS_PRODUCTOS_RESUMEN)
    ResponseEntity<MyClass> getHola(@Valid @RequestBody final MyRequest request);
}
```

My implementation

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(/api/holamundo)
public class MyControlller implements HelloApi {

        private final HelloService helloService;
    
    public DescuentoProductoController(HelloService helloService){
              this.helloService=helloService;
    }

       
        @Override
        public ResponseEntity<MyClass> getHola(MyRequest request){
              this.helloService.getHola(request);
    }

        

}
```

I need to make a test in mockito that passes through HandleException and does not pass the coverage

My Test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyControlllerTest {

        .....
    @Mock
     HelloService helloService;

        MyControlller controller;


       @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        controller = new MyControlller(helloservice);

    }
.....
        @Test
    void test() {
        controller.getHola(request);        
        assertTrue(true);
        
    }
```

It should fall into the coverage and it does not go through the handlerexception when I do the test, how do I make it go through the coverage

A hand with this, thank you very much in advance.

A hand with this, thank you very much in advance.